# Writing caption of a post on Instagram using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

As the caption says.

Right now this is what I am doing.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > div.A9bvI > section.IpSxo > div.NfvXc > textarea').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > div.A9bvI > section.IpSxo > div.NfvXc > textarea').clear()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > div.A9bvI > section.IpSxo > div.NfvXc > textarea').send_keys(caption)
```

I tried a few different ways like using xpath and moving around the .click(), .clear(), .send_keys() but nothing seems to work. None of the solutions provided to similar questions here have worked either.

Answer (score 1):

Found it - the issue in my case was there was some error in the caption, when I passed a normal string, it worked. Specifically, it was an emoji. You may want to remove it if you get the same error.

Comment: As the issue was in incorrect passed string please delete the question as it doesn't seem to be useful for SO Community

Comment: Specific for "some error in the caption" please. And your full selenium script to have the full context e.g. what url you are starting with on instagram.

Comment: I added the specific problem in my case - which happened to be an emoji. If you still think it is irrelevant let me know and I will delete it.